# How to load image from assets folder react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native app. And I try to load a default image from the assets folder. I have ini the assets folder a image with name icon_detail.png. And I try to load the image.

```
export const CategoryInfoCard = ({ category = {} }) => {
    const {
        name = "Zoogdieren",
        images = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492_960_720.jpg",
        icon = "./assets/icon_detail.png",
    } = category;

    return (
        <CategoryCard
            elevation={5}
            style={{
                borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                borderTopRightRadius: 0,
                borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
                borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
            }}>
            <Title center variant="h1" style={{ left: 100 }}>
                {name}
            </Title>
            <CategoryGroupCardCover source={{ uri: images }} />
            <Spacer style={{ width: 15, height: 15 }}>
                <Icon source={require({ uri: icon })} />
            </Spacer>
        </CategoryCard>
    );
};
```

Icons source looks:

```
export const Icon = styled.Image`
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
`;
```

But I get this error:

```
src\features\animalGroup\components\category-info-card.component.js: src\features\animalGroup\components\category-info-card.component.js:Invalid call at line 46: require({
  uri: icon
})
```

Comment: I also tried like: but then nothing is displayed: <Icon source={{ uri: "./assets/images/information_icon.png" }} />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using require wrong. Here's the right way to include an image in React Native `require('/path-to-image/...png')`.

Your source prop should either be `source={{ uri: 'http://....' }}` or `source={require('/path-to-image/img.png')}`.

You can find more information [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images) on the image component and requiring assets.